# Ubuntu Intell display monitor is not working

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, 22.04, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime

so I have ubuntu installed on my pc with 3 monitors connected. Two which are connected to my RTX 2060 super GPU and 1 is connected to my motherboard (intel)

I decided to install the Nvidia drivers in the additional drivers app of ubuntu and when I rebooted my pc only the Nvidia monitors work, the monitor connected to the motherboard is blank

Is there any way to fix this?